# Why isn't the value being printed?

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard

Here's the short code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myKeyPress(e)
    {
        var keynum;
        var list;
        if(window.event)
        {                   
            keynum = e.keyCode;
            list = keynum;
            if(list == 115)
            {
                alert("You pressed the 'S' key.");
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
    <form>
        <input type="text" onkeypress="myKeyPress(event);"/>
    </form>
```

When I hit a key, myKeyPress should be called and the event should be passed to the function. In the function body, e (the event parameter) should fetch the Keynum and obtain the input value. That value should be 115 if I were to press 'S' on the keyboard. List should then have the value of Keynum, and list is checked to see if its value is equal to 115 (it should be). If so, it should alert the corresponding text in a message box on the screen. It doesn't do it though. Why?

Comment: You're missing several closing `}` characters, you should be getting a syntax error.

Comment: Doesn't work even after closing brackets are insterted.

Comment: I'm not sure if `window.event` is portable. Why are you testing that instead of `e`?

Comment: BTW, do you have an allergy to proper indentation?

Comment: @Barmar I've tested window.event class and it works fine with other programs, such as obtaining coordinates on the screen, but it's not working with the keypress. And yes, just look at my name.

Comment: It works for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/5FL79/

Comment: @Barmar Must be something specific about IE 10 then (the browser I'm using).

Comment: I tried my fiddle in IE 10 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shortened version of your code:

```
function myKeyPress(e) {
    var keynum = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    alert(keynum); // Just to see all key presses, remove when done :)
    if (keynum == 115) {
        alert("You pressed the 'S' key.");
    }
}
```

I am binding it using JavaScript not using an HTML attribute:

```
document.getElementById('example').onkeypress = myKeyPress;
```

So I added an ID:

```
<input type="text" id="example" />
```

I find that this works. I'm not sure why you were testing `window.event` in your code?

Comment: Okay, my statement should have been "I'm not sure why you are testing `window.event` when you don't then use it". Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score -1):

s key is nr **83** and not 115.

you could find out like this with jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myinput').on('keyup',function(e){
 console.log(e.keyCode);
}); 
</script>

<input type="text" id="myinput" />
```

Comment: 83 is uppercase S, 115 is lowercase S

Comment: Barmar, When I try my code, it shows 83 on lowercase s. Can you explain where you get 115 from? Can you make me a test script that prove your theory?

Comment: From http://www.asciitable.com/ Uppercase letters are 65-90, lowercase are 97-122.

Comment: It looks like jQuery is canonicalizing keycodes. I get different results depending on whether I write the handler in raw JS or jQuery.

Comment: Actually, the difference is in the event. The question uses `keypress`, your code uses `keyup`. The `keypress` event includes the effect of the shift key, so it distinguishes upper and lower case. The `keyup` event doesn't, and it always returns uppercase letters.